# How to add Values to custom dimension at runtime - Azure application insights

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, azure-api-apps

I'm trying to add my own custom dimension values for each API request in the azure app insights.

As per [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling#add-properties-itelemetryinitializer), we can use ITelemetryInitializer interface to initialize and add our own custom dimension values. But while doing that we are simply hardcoding the values, but my values will change at runtime

For E.g this [S.O](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39841593/7073340) is showed he added custom property "LoggedInUserName" under the Custom group of request properties, by hardcoding the value as **DummyUser**

But my values will get changed during the runtime. So how will I track that for each request?

If it's not possible to track at the request level. Can we track this at trace level?

Thanks in Advance,
Jay

Comment: Check [this repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/tree/3567c4af164a0e01ee0630b8d77251171ba7d42b/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/TelemetryInitializers) for some examples. If you want the username, try [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/blob/3567c4af164a0e01ee0630b8d77251171ba7d42b/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/TelemetryInitializers/WebUserTelemetryInitializer.cs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For request-specific custom dimensions the recommendation is:
1) Populate needed data as Tags on Activity object
2) Add TelemetryInitializer which will copy Tags from Activity to custom dimensions

For more details you can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49392526/3646920