# Web API + Azure App Insights pass the data from ActionFilter to ITelemetryProcessor

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights, actionfilterattribute

I'd like to customize my Application Insights logging behavior. So I'd like to set some sort of flag in my **ActionFilter** and then read that flag in **ITelemetryProcessor**.

```
public class MyCustomFilterAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {
        //perform some logic and set the flag here
    }
}
```

and then

```
public class TelemetryFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        var request = item as RequestTelemetry;
        //read the flag here and terminate processing
    }
}
```

Is that possible ? Is there some sort of TempData that's shared between those two types ? I'd like to avoid kind of hacks like setting temporary header and so on. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this will be useful. But I hope will be.

Using `Activity.Current`

```
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        Activity current = Activity.Current;

        if (current == null)
        {
            current = (Activity)HttpContext.Current?.Items["__AspnetActivity__"];
//put your code here
        }
}
```

Refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49392526/7073340)

Comment: yes it could be a solution, thank you. I was wondering if there is something built-in in Azure AI but `HttpContext.Current` can solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

Write a TelemetryInitializer where you have access to HttpContext.

//TelemetryInitializer

```
public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
     var ctx = HttpContext.Current; // Telemetry Initialzer runs in same thread as the request.
     var request = item as RequestTelemetry;
     req.Properties.Add("MyActionFilter", "MyActionFilterValue")
     ...
    }
```

//TelemetryProcessor

```
public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        var request = item as RequestTelemetry;
        //read the flag here and terminate processing
        if(req.Properties["MyActionFilter"] == "somthing")
        {
        ...
        }
    }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling#itelemetryprocessor-and-itelemetryinitializer

For Asp.Net Core, injecting `IHttpContextAccessor` to the TelemetryInitializer constructor can get you context, as done here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/blob/develop/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/TelemetryInitializers/TelemetryInitializerBase.cs

Comment: Thanks, it looks like something I'm looking for. The thing is that I'm not using .NET Core and currently installed NuGet package ( `version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net452"`) is not able to recognize `IHttpContextAccessor` is it something .NET Core specific ?

Comment: For regular (non .net core) you can access `HttpContext.Current`, from a `TelemetryInitializer` as they are run in the same thread as the request. You can inspect the context and set some properties on the Telemetry from the initializer. And later use a `TelemetryProcessor` to take action based on the property set by Initializer.